# Error combining 'if' statements that null-checks and Pattern Matches

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

The following works as expected:

```
dynamic foo = GetFoo();

if (foo != null)
{
    if (foo is Foo i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.Bar);
    }
}
```

but if I combine the if statements like so:

```
if (foo != null && foo is Foo i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.Bar);
}
```

then I receive a compiler warning

`Use of unassigned local variable 'i'`

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: I agree - this looks like a compiler bug. You should report it to Microsoft. I think bug reports go here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues

Comment: Well spotted. Would agree that this looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: Works well, btw, if `foo` is `object`. Some troubles with `dynamic` here.

Comment: That should be the place to report this bug: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: Has it already been reported? Is it this? https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/25718

Comment: @MatthewWatson Good spot, agree that's the same thing and this isn't a "bug", more an esoteric feature of `dynamic` and just more ammunition why it should be used only where absolutely necessary.

Comment: Just to be complete though, `if (foo is Foo i)` returns `false` when foo is null so for this particular situation it does not matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would appear that this is not, in fact, a compiler error.

It was previously reported as a bug [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/25718).

However, it has been closed as not a bug. The reason is because of this part of the C# language spec (note: I am quoting here from user `gafter` on GitHub - this is NOT original content from myself):

> If an operand of a conditional logical operator has the compile-time type dynamic, then the expression is dynamically bound (Dynamic binding). In this case the compile-time type of the expression is dynamic, and the resolution described below will take place at run-time using the run-time type of those operands that have the compile-time type dynamic.

Specifically, the && operation is not a compile-time boolean short-circuiting operation because its right-hand operand is of type dynamic.

Subtle stuff, and as DavidG says above, another reason to avoid `dynamic` where possible! (And I must confess, I'm still not completely convinced it's *not* a bug, but that's just me not understanding everything I guess...)

Comment: So if it was an `&` operation it would compile?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Having tried it, no it still doesn't compile.

Comment: Wow... I've just tested and you really have to put it like 
    if ((bool)(foo != null) && foo is Foo i )  
to work...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was thinking for some time about this issue, and it looks that compiler behavior is pretty damn correct and it's not so hard to reproduce it even without `dynamic` values.

Some strange code will be required, nevertheless.

To start with we will overload `&&` operator for our `Foo` type. It's not possible to overload short circuit logical operators directly, so we will overload `true`, `false` and `&` separately.

```
public static bool operator true(Foo x) => true;
public static bool operator false(Foo x) => true;
public static Foo operator &(Foo foo, Foo val) => new Foo();
```

Initially we had an expression `foo != null && foo is Foo i` in `if` block, now we want `&&` from it to bound to our overload. For this reason we will overload `!=` operator and `==` as well as they should be paired always.

```
public static Foo operator !=(Foo val, Foo val2) => new Foo();  
public static Foo operator ==(Foo val, Foo val2) => new Foo();
```

For now `foo != null` evaluates to `Foo` and `foo is Foo` evaluates to `bool`, but our `&&` overload has signature `(Foo, Foo)` — still a mismatch, will add one more overload for implicit conversion from `bool`.

```
public static implicit operator Foo(bool val) => new Foo();
```

Here is the code for `Foo` type we've got so far

```
class Foo
{
    public static bool operator true(Foo x) => true;
    public static bool operator false(Foo x) => true;
    public static Foo operator &(Foo foo, Foo val) => new Foo();

    public static implicit operator Foo(bool val) => new Foo();

    public static Foo operator !=(Foo val, Foo val2) => new Foo();
    public static Foo operator ==(Foo val, Foo val2) => new Foo();
}
```

And voila! We have the same error for this piece.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Foo foo = GetFoo();

     if (foo != null && foo is Foo i)
     {
         // Use of unassigned local variable i
         // Local variable 'i' might not be initialized before accessing 
         Console.WriteLine(i);
     }
 }

 static Foo GetFoo() => new Foo();
```

And indeed, if we for example use `foo is string i` instead of `foo is Foo i`, `i` won't be initialized at runtime, but we will be inside `if` block.

Initial issue is rather equivalent, because of `dynamic` values involved. `foo != null` is `dynamic`, as far as `foo` is `dynamic`, so it means `&&` should be bound at runtime, and we have no guarantees that `i` will be initialized.

Looks like Matthew quoted the same thing from github issue, but I personally wasn't able to grasp it from the beginning.