# Why ! operator works while == false doesn't in this case?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I though `condition == false` is equivalent to `!( condition )`  but I found that they behave differently with is keyword.

When I use `!( condition )` the code compiles successfully:

```
object instance = "Hello world!";
if( !( instance is string value ) )
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
Console.WriteLine( value );
```

However compiler throws following error if I use `condition == false`

> CS0165    Use of unassigned local variable 'value'

[image]

```
object instance = "Hello world!";
if( instance is string value == false )
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
Console.WriteLine( value );
```

What is the differece between `condition == false` and `!( condition )` in this case?

Comment: `((instance is string) == false)` Still throws error :(

Comment: I guess you need to put your exact condition example if you want satisfactory answer.

Comment: This problem only appear when I use is keyword to convert type.

Comment: not reproducible for me in VS 2017

Comment: What error do you mean ? is it throwing the exception you are throwing (InvalidOperationException) or do you still have some compiler error? If I fix the "value" thing, my instance is actually a string. so condition is not false, so I am getting the WriteLine atm.

Comment: I just see your added screenshot, what to you want the "value" to be?

Comment: More specifically, I don't know why compiler think 'value' variable is unassigned when I use `== false`. Seems that some people can't reproduce this so I'm now suspecting that my compiler is broken or something.

Comment: See marked duplicate. While the original question uses `dynamic`, that's not strictly required, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50377534) illustrates. Briefly: the `==` operator can be overloaded, which changes the compiler's analysis of definite assignment, as compared to the unary `!` operator. Note that changes to the definite assignment analysis can affect this (since there are always things that a human can demonstrate are definitely assigned, but which the compiler can't, there will always be gaps, but sometimes these gaps are closed).

Comment: Given the behavior could depend on the compiler version, you should be clear about what version of Visual Studio and/or what C# compiler you're using. As noted, VS2017 is able to determine the variable is definitely assigned.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm using VS2017 C#7.3. I've read that answer but I'm still confusing.  First, the answer demonstrate an error by overloading operator of a foo class but I don't think == operator in `instance is string value == false ` can be overloaded because it's operator of bool type. Second, the original question includes `foo != null` so operator overloading can makes things different but it's not true in my case.

Comment: _You_ can't overload the operator, because you don't have control over `bool`. But the `==` operator itself is overloadable. You will find that in the case of the definite assignment rules, the compiler implementation does not necessarily make every analytical effort that you might as a human. It is literally impossible for the compiler to know 100% of the time when a variable that _is_ definitely assigned, that it is actually definitely assigned (see "halting problem"). So the implementation focuses on the most practical scenarios, and ignores ones that might require overly significant effort